# How is it possible to make an object array public with a variable

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I want this following array to be public with a int variable to two functions.
I do not know how to write this as a struct. I know this struct can be GET and SET but I am stuck on how to write  for this array. This has been nagging me about C OOP for a long time.

```
int pixelCount = 0

public CustomVertex.TransformedColored[] points_data 
                             = new CustomVertex.TransformedColored[pixelCount];
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what your question is

Comment: @Jamiec yeah I tried, but I could only fix cosmetic issues in the hopes someone else could understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>My mindreading skills are at half tilt today, if Ive got this entirely wrong I apologise.</sub>

I *think* what you're after is an [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), which allows you to add array-like get/set access to your own classes.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private CustomVertex.TransformedColored[] points_data;

    public CustomVertex.TransformedColored this[int pixelCount]
    {
       get{ return points_data[pixelCount]; }
       set{ points_data[pixelCount] = value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 var obj = new MyClass();
 obj[0] = some_value; //set
 var result = obj[0]; // get
```

Comment: When I set, the compiler throws an error.
            var objPoints = new PointsDataClass();
            objPoints[0] = CustomVertex.TransformedColored[countPixels];

Error 1 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.CustomVertex.TransformedColored' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: You have to do it on an *instance* of `MyClass` not the class itself.

Comment: I think I know where the confusion is. I don't want an array of CustomVertex.TransformedColored objects. I want one public object CustomVertex.TransformedColored where pixelCount sets the size of CustomVertex.TransformedColored

Comment: Cool, glad you found your issue.

Comment: Getting error trying to SET. Cannot modify the return value of 'Object_Namespace.Form1.PointsDataClass.this[int]' 


                    objPoints[pointCount].X = (float)(item1);
                    objPoints[pointCount].Y = (float)(item2);
                    objPoints[pointCount].Z = 1.0f;
                    objPoints[pointCount].Rhw = 1.0f;
                    objPoints[pointCount].Color = Color.White.ToArgb();

Please help.

Comment: ... because it is not a variable

Comment: It is still not possible to publicly access the stored objects from the class in across different functions.